# Akka remote deployment configuration

Tags: scala, akka

When learning how to distribute Actor Systems to remote server I came across 2 ways to define this in the configuration file.

The first is:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}
```

My question is about the line `provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"`
In another example I found this:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}
```

Here they use `provider = remote`.

My question is what the difference between these 2 is. Is there any or do they do the same thing underwater and is the 2nd way just an easier way to write it?

Comment: I'm not sure about how the config resolution works for relative paths, but I'd guess that it would look for "remote" under "actor" first and then possibly bubble up. But the bubbling up bit I'm not sure. Are you 100% positive the 2nd example was working?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I am not 100% sure, but since it comes from the Akka docs (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/remoting.html) it seems safe to assume that it does.

Comment: Please report this to the Akka people then :)